# How to find which entity that a security privilege is related to?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-365

I'm modifying the security roles of a specific user to give him as minimal access as possible to do certain stuff only (assign security roles, create workflows, etc.) How can I determine the entity related to a security privilege?

For example, `prvCreateBusinessUnit` privilege is related to Business Unit entity. However, what about other privileges such as `prvReadProfileRule`? what entity is it related to?

I've two important information that may be helpful:

1-Privilege name
2-Privilege Id

Comment: How about you use XrmToolBox and plugin named "Metadata Browser".
Check there if you can find any entity with Profile Rule.
In one of my instance when I gave Profile Rule I received 2 entities.

ChannelAccessProfileRule and ChannelAccessProfileRuleItem

Answer (score 1):

Your original plan is not going to be that simple.

> user A cannot assign a Security Role to user B, if it gives user B privileges higher than has User A

[Creating a security role to be able to only create roles and users without having system admin role](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42887720/7920473)

Each security role consists of record-level privileges and task-based privileges, former takes care of transaction data entries whereas later privileges are needed like Export to Excel", Data Import, Publish articles, etc.

Read more: [Security roles and privileges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/admin/security-roles-privileges) (the latest documentation)

I would recommend you to build some custom .Net or Angular application to elevate your admins to do this action of assigning roles, etc and Impersonation can help to leverage the Service account for achieving it in background. Minimum HTML web resource can be used within Dynamics.

**Another most important point**:

> Do not create a new security role from scratch. Copy an existing role and modify it. There are 580 pre-defined privileges, hence this is the better way of doing it and it also maintains consistency

[Reference](https://crmbook.powerobjects.com/system-administration/business-administration/security-roles/)

Answer (score 0):

By convention the name is prv[Privilege][Entity]
Here is a listing of all privileges and which entity they apply to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/hh547441(v=crm.8)

prvReadProfileRule does not appear, where are you seeing that?

Update:
Minimum permissions to log into application:
https://www.inogic.com/blog/2016/11/minimum-privileges-required-to-login-microsoft-dynamics-365/

Minimum permissions to view account and contact records:
https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f52f26e5-8684-4fd7-a89f-4dd34972c0ed/minimum-security-permissions-to-view-accounts-amp-contacts?forum=crm

Comment: i'm getting this privilege name from the log file when the exception is fired. The most important line in the log file is **<Message>RoleService::VerifyCallerPrivileges failed. User: a3b660d9-aa05-e311-978f-005056a1577e, PrivilegeName: prvReadProfileRule, PrivilegeId: a643d6fe-3212-4813-90cb-89ea1c2b6d40, Depth: Local, BusinessUnitId: aa853d55-f7f4-db11-9cc0-0015c5e5e940</Message>**

Comment: What action are you attempting that returns this result? I updated my answer with a couple links related to minimum privileges which I have found useful in the past. I assume you checked and there are no custom entities with a name similar to this?

Comment: i'm attempting to add a security role for a user. I already have a set of privileges assigned to this user and i'm trying to add more privileges to enable him to do such thing. 

I've a few more examples, **prvOneDrive, prvReadOfficeGraphDocument, and prvReadAzureServiceConnection**.

Can I assign those privileges using database queries, c# code,or  PowerShell ? I tried a plugin on XrmToolBox (called Role Updater) and it assigns privileges temporarily for some reason.

Comment: To clarify, your attempt with this user to assign security privileges for another user is throwing the exception? You can assign roles using c# code (recommended) or via direct database access (not recommended, but sometimes expedient). I would ask this as a separate question.

Comment: Let's say we have user A and user B. I'm adding privileges to user A to enable him to assign security roles to user B. When user A tries to assign a security role to user B, he gets an exception.

Answer (score 0):

ReadProfileRule is the entity "Channel access profile rule"
you can find this by opening role updater plugin in XRMToolbox, and searching the permission name "ReadProfileRule".
it seems that this entity isn't appearing under security roles for some environments,
but the permission can be added through role updater plugin  in XRMtoolbox.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).